# Applications of a theorem of M. H. Stone to general topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, lattice-orders

Exercise 2.I of J. Kelley's book *General Topology* introduces a theorem by M.H. Stone concerning maximal ideals in distributive lattices. The statement is the following :

> Let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint subsets of a distributive lattice $X$ such that $A$ is an ideal and $B$ is a dual ideal.
> Then there are disjoint sets $A'$ and $B'$ such that $A'$ is an ideal containing $A$, $B'$ is a dual ideal containing $B$, and $X=A' \cup B'$.

Kelley writes that Stone's theorem is "the best form of one of the basic facts about ordered sets."

Stone's original proof is actually hard to follow, but I am interested in *applications* of his result. For instance, Exercise 2.J of Kelley's book uses Stone's theorem to prove that any net has a subnet which is universal. Even the proof of Tychonoff's theorem about compact spaces can be based on Stone's theorem. Unfortunately, I cannot find any book or expository paper in which this approach based on ordered sets is used for proving results in general topology. Does anybody know a reference?

Comment: Please forgive me if this is a vain remark and you mean something else, but the first thing I immediately remembered was wonderful book Birkhoff G. - Lattice theory- 3d edition (1973). There is just a section APPLICATIONS TO GENERAL TOPOLOGY on page 211 and, accordingly, subsection Stone Representation Theorem on page 226. Hope helps.

Comment: @zkutch Thank you very much, I have just noticed that my 2nd edition of Birkhoff's book does not contain that chapter. I will try to find it.